# How to make Multiple items purchase using Google Play in-app billing

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I am working on a project where we sell variety of game-sets. I want to show these game-sets and let him buy multiple game-sets at once. But the Google's in-app billing takes only one item at a time.Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't an option to allow multiple purchases at once, perhaps consider offering bundles which will unlock multiple game sets. 
I've seen both a "popular" bundle of the ones that most go for and also "total" bundles where the purchaser gets everything.